# borrowed value does not live long enough in this case ( Vec<&Fn(i32) -> i32> )

Tags: rust

I am having this error, other times I had something similar and I have been able to solve, in different ways but now is not how to solve in this case:

> borrowed value does not live long enough in

I moved the code that fails one more simple, but I can not find the error:

```
fn main(){

    let mut v: Vec<&Fn(i32) -> i32> = Vec::new();

    v.push(&ops_code1);
    //v.push(&ops_code2);
    //v.push(&ops_code3);
}

fn ops_code1(value: i32) -> i32 {
..//
```

> error: borrowed value does not live long enough
>
> v.push(&ops_code1);

<kbd>[play.rust](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=974426b4f90adb0775e1d58d74e8d6c2&version=stable&backtrace=0)</kbd>

Comment: Can you share the whole file, in https://play.rust-lang.org/ ?

Comment: @CengizCan sure looks update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing here is creating a Vec of closures. In Rust static functions are treated slightly differently from closures, so when we create the reference a closure is actually created. If we do that after creating the Vec the resulting closure gets a shorter lifetime than the Vec, which is an error. We can instead use a let to create the closure *before* the Vec, giving a long enough lifetime, outliving the Vec:

```
fn main() {
    let extended = &ops_code1;

    let mut v: Vec<&Fn(i32) -> i32> = Vec::new();

    // Note that placing it here does not work:
    // let extended = &ops_code1;

    v.push(extended);
    //v.push(&ops_code2);
    //v.push(&ops_code3);

}

fn ops_code1(value: i32) -> i32 {
    println!("ops_code1 {}", value);
    value
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2027663caa7bce8d9bb779cf06bd711e&version=stable&backtrace=0)

However, if you only use static functions - and not closures - the following also works fine, and lets you avoid the extra let:

```
fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<fn(i32) -> i32> = Vec::new();

    v.push(ops_code1);
    v.push(ops_code2);
}

fn ops_code1(value: i32) -> i32 {
    println!("ops_code1 {}", value);
    value
}

fn ops_code2(value: i32) -> i32 {
    println!("ops_code2 {}", value);
    value
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=db55f6ae6ba1c4eeab5ad9b4b9bb02bc&version=stable&backtrace=0)

A third option is to use boxed closures, which let's you use both closures and static functions without the extra lets, but with its own trade-offs:

```
fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<Box<Fn(i32) -> i32>> = Vec::new();

    v.push(Box::new(ops_code1));
    v.push(Box::new(ops_code2));

    for f in v {
      f(1);
    }
}

fn ops_code1(value: i32) -> i32 {
    println!("ops_code1 {}", value);
    value
}

fn ops_code2(value: i32) -> i32 {
    println!("ops_code2 {}", value);
    value
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4f2799809d9c1d5bc2dcd6233852b83b&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Comment: thanks really is useful, but I have a question, I have to create as many, let extended = &ops_codeX; as functions I have? , there is no other way to do this without creating let. edit: I'm new to Rust but I think your update is what I use, thanks for your time

Comment: The let is to essentially use a static function as a closure. So it is needed once per static function(for the first alternative). Did some more reading on the topic, I'll extend my answer to explain further.

Comment: thanks for the details but I can not give more votes sorry

Comment: Of course, no problem. Just wanted to improve my answer as I further understood the issue. :)